# Strange Issue with Primary Key Addition

Tags: sql-server, primary-key

I am using SQL server 2008 r2. 
I was creating a table implicitly i.e without writing queries and tried to add primary key to one of the column by right clicking and selecting primary key.
But i could not add the primary key as it was not reflected there, i refreshed the table , the database and also closed the connection and re-connected but primary key was still not reflected on that column name. I tried this thrice.

Then I added primary key using query (Table was empty)

```
alter table [Table Name]
Add Primary key ([column name])
```

and then it got reflected in the table.

I tried searching for reason but could not find any convincing reason.

If anybody knows reason for this please reply.

Comment: Your syntax to add Primary Key isnt right. try the one I have mentioned in my answer.

Comment: Personally  I think you should get out of the habit of using teh GUI to create tables. It is a very poor practice (especially to change existing tables!!) SQL code (including creating tables, views, etc.) should be done in scripts and put under source control.

Comment: the query which i have mentioned is just to tell that i used alter table query to add primary key. main question is why did primary key do not add when i was trying to add it without using query i.e by just right clicking the column name while creating the table and selecting primary key.That is the question, not how to add a primary key using query.

Answer (score 2):

```
ALTER TABLE [TableName]  
ADD CONSTRAINT [PrimaryKeyName] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([ExistingColumn])
```

Make sure the column is NOT NULL i.e doesnt allow NULL values to be inserted.

Comment: The code which i have mentioned will work absolutely fine, try it urself just add your table name and primary key column.                  Alter Table [table name]                                                add primary key ([column name]).    Do it on an empty table and make the column NOT NULL

Answer (score 1):

Please check that you have **"UNCHECKED"** checkbox which says Prevent saving changes that require the table re-creation. You can follow below instruction to uncheck it.

1. Open SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS).
2. On the Tools menu, click Options.
3. In the navigation pane of the Options window, click Designers.
4. Select or clear the Prevent saving changes that require the table
   re-creation check box, and then click OK.

[image]

Comment: I have unchecked it, but the point is that it is not the first time i am using GUI to create table and adding constraints. with the similar settings i have added primary key to the table many times. But this time why did it happen?

Comment: any ways +1 for your effort